# How to get all authenticated and public communities in a org via Apex

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I am working on a lightning component which would allow the admin to select what type of community: **Authenticated** or **Public**. After selecting the community type, I need to show the relevant communities in the view.

I checked the [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm) object to see if there's field which I could use to decide a particular community is public or not but I don't find any such field to do so.

Is there's a way to get all the public and authenticated communities in Apex?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [Connect API Community methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_Communities_static_methods.htm) to get a listing of communities and details around them, There isn't a straight Public/Authenticated status to check. But this will get you the listing of all communities you have access to